# php running in background through shell

Tags: php, background, cron, execution

Created a cron which indeed executes in every six hours which does create a shell script with different input to store.php every time it is executed.
* */6 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/execute.php > /dev/null &

execute.php will create the test.sh file with following commands and executes test.sh

/usr/bin/php /var/www/store.php 'x' > /dev/null &
/usr/bin/php /var/www/store.php 'y' > /dev/null &

it executes successfully and the logic is done. but when I checked through top command on shell

$top

I see all the php process running continuously, even after the execution is completed.
I want it to run the php code only once but it is still running in background... how should I stop it and how to do it only once... even added exit in php file(store.php at the end)....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to end a script, you can use a [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) statement at the end of the file. Or you can simply call [`exit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php). However, the script SHOULD end it's self once it get's to the last line. Suggesting that the script is not ever getting to the end of the file ... I would recomend putting in some echo statements at various parts of the file and making sure that it actually get's to the end of the file.

Comment: I've added exit at the end the script. But I don't know why php script is running continuously when it doesn't have any loop...

Comment: I recomend putting in some echo statements into that file and then flushing out the output of the program to a file so that you can see how far it get's into it's execution. If you know it only takes like a half second for the whole thing to run, you could set the scripts max execution time to like 10 seconds with [`set_time_limit(10)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) and that will kill the script after 10 seconds (most of the time.)